# Match unique values to specific columns and their fields using python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a datset, df, where I would like to place certain values in a column depending upon a value in a nearby column:

**Data:**

```
dc  country type
    eu      am7
    america bww
    uk      cww
    eu      dub1
    ap      hn
```

**Desired:**

I wish to populate the dc column with specific values based upon the value within the type column. If the value in type column is am7, the dc value will be 1000 etc

```
dc      country type
1000    eu      am7
500     america bww
200     uk      cww
100     eu      dub1
200     ap      hn
```

**Doing:**

I believe I have to do a mapping or dictionary within Python and Pandas:

```
dc = {
  'am7': 1000,
  'bww': 500,
  'cww': 200,
  'dub1': 100,
  'hn':200
}

df['dc'] = df['type'].map(dc)
```

The desired column is not populating with the desired values.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: That should work... what is wrong with the output you're getting?

Comment: Your example that you have included works correctly?

Comment: If not working, maybe `type` contains leading/trailing whitespace?  You can try `df['dc'] = df['type'].str.strip().map(dc)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as expected:

```py
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO("""\
dc  country type
    eu      am7
    america bww
    uk      cww
    eu      dub1
    ap      hn\
"""))

dc = {
  'am7': 1000,
  'bww': 500,
  'cww': 200,
  'dub1': 100,
  'hn':200
}

>>> df
   dc  country  type
0 NaN       eu   am7
1 NaN  america   bww
2 NaN       uk   cww
3 NaN       eu  dub1
4 NaN       ap    hn
```

```
df['dc'] = df['type'].map(dc)

>>> df
     dc  country  type
0  1000       eu   am7
1   500  america   bww
2   200       uk   cww
3   100       eu  dub1
4   200       ap    hn
```

@AlexK 's suggestion is right, remove extra whitespaces if applicable:

```
df = df.merge(df.select_dtypes("object").applymap(str.strip), how="right")
```